# Magento 2.3: Can backend pages be cached as well?

Tags: magento2.3, cache, admin-panel

My impression is that Magento (2.3.5) does not apply caching on pages in the backend. Is this as intended? If so, why? If not, can caching get enabled for backend pages?

Comment: can you explain why you want the backend pages to be cached ?

Comment: @Ekk4rd Why not? What would be a problem? But also because my backend is slow. Probably caused by other problems, but I thought caching could improve the situation anyway.

Comment: because in the backend you want to manage and see the actual data in the database; not the cached data.

Comment: @Ekk4rd That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend (Admin) pages are not cached because you see all your data live. Caching means it turns your page into a static page without having to access the database or process PHP. If you did this in your Admin you would not see real-time data.